Proving the frequency shifting property using duality
I'm trying to use the duality property:
$$g(t) \leftrightarrow G(j\omega) \implies G(t) \leftrightarrow 2\pi g(-j\omega)$$
and the time-shifting property:
$$x(t-t_0) \leftrightarrow e^{-j\omega t_0}X(j\omega)$$
to prove the frequency shifting property:
$$e^{j\omega_0t}X(t) \leftrightarrow \hat{X}(j(\omega-\omega_0))$$
(where $\hat X(t)$ is the fourier transform of $X(t)$ to avoid confusion).
Applying the duality property to the time-shifting property
$$e^{-j\omega_0 \tau}X(j\tau) \leftrightarrow 2\pi x(-(\omega - \omega_0))$$
Then replacing the RHS by $\hat X(j\omega) = 2\pi x(-j\omega)$:
$$e^{-j\omega_0 \tau}X(j\tau) \leftrightarrow \hat X(j(\omega-\omega_0))$$
Now replacing $j\tau$ with $t$ (s.t. $\tau = -jt$) we have:
$$e^{\omega_0 t}X(t) \leftrightarrow \hat X(j(\omega-\omega_0))$$
But now I've lost my $j$. What have I done wrong?

a) you need to be careful with you Transform variables. The FT is defined between two  variables $t$ and $\omega$ which can both be complex. Writing the frequency side as $X*(j \omega)$  is a somewhat questionable convention.. Try $x(t) \leftrightarrow X(\omega)$ instead. b) This one is easy to proof directly from the definition. so no need to derive it from other properties.

You got the duality property wrong. Using $X(j\omega)$ to denote the Fourier transform of $x(t)$, the duality property is
$$x(t) \leftrightarrow X(j\omega) \implies X(jt) \leftrightarrow 2\pi x(-\omega)\tag{1}$$
Note that with this notation there's always a $j$ in the argument of $X(\cdot)$, and never in the argument of $x(\cdot)$, no matter if the independent variable is time or frequency. So you always just exchange the variables $t$ and $\omega$, possibly with a negative sign, but never with a multiplication of $j$.
Now you can show the modulation property as the dual of the time shifting property:
From
$$x(t-t_0)\leftrightarrow e^{-j\omega t_0}X(j\omega)\tag{2}$$
we obtain via $(1)$
$$e^{-j\omega_0 t}X(jt)\leftrightarrow 2\pi x(-\omega-\omega_0)=2\pi x(-(\omega+\omega_0))\tag{3}$$
If we use $\hat{X}(j\omega)$ to denote the Fourier transform of $X(jt)$ we obtain from $(1)$
$$\hat{X}(j\omega)=2\pi x(-\omega)\tag{4}$$
Plugging $(4)$ into $(3)$ we get
$$e^{-j\omega_0 t}X(jt)\leftrightarrow \hat{X}(j(\omega+\omega_0))\tag{5}$$
Of course we can change the sign of $\omega_0$ to obtain the following more common form of the modulation property:
$$e^{j\omega_0 t}X(jt)\leftrightarrow \hat{X}(j(\omega-\omega_0))\tag{6}$$
